Viber notifications are on the wrong place
I've installed the latest Ubuntu 24.04 and the latest Viber AppImage. I have 3 monitors. My primary monitor is the one in the middle and my notifications are in the middle monitor on the top right corner. However that rule doesn't apply for Viber. If I have Viber opened on the left monitor, the notifications to Viber go on that monitor on the bottom right corner.
It drives me crazy. Any suggestions other than removing Viber?

Which version of Viber are you using? There are at least 3 I know about: the appimage, the flatpack and the unofficial_viber from the snap shop.

The appImage one. I've contacted the viber support team and I was told this is not bug and there is nothing I can do about. It is working as intended.
